# Create bearer token within Swagger UI

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.2, openiddict

We have an ASP.NET WebApi project base on .NET Core 2.2 and we're using bearer token via open id for authentication.

Actually I only can create a bearer token using postman, where I can define a x-www-form-urlencoded body containing the authorization properties like username and password.

I already added a security definition to the option of the swaggergen in the startup class:

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", 
                        new ApiKeyScheme()
                            {
                                In = "header",
                                Description = "Please insert Bearer JWT token into field. Example: 'Bearer {token}'",
                                Name = "Authorization",
                                Type = "apiKey"
                            });
```

But I still have to create the bearer token via postman. How can I create it via the Swagger UI, too?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("OpenID Connect", new OAuth2Scheme
                                                                    {
                                                                        Type = "oauth2",
                                                                        Flow = "implicit",
                                                                        AuthorizationUrl = "/connect/authorize"
                    });
```

...

```
options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize")
                            .AllowImplicitFlow()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom swagger authorization to enter the necessary fields to get bearer token back and and store it. You can have a look at something like this: http://www.geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2015/06/26/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle.aspx.

If you want to create it via swagger, add a custom end point to your solution which would work only in dev environment if intended like that.